# GF(2^n) Multiplication using normal base

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-algebra-systems

I want to implement the multiplication using normal basis in the binary field $GF(2^n)$ (where n=163, 233 for example). The multiplication with normal basis is performed by $c_0=A*M*B^T$, where $M$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, and $c_0$ is one bit of $C=A*B$.

Is there any software or program that can support such multiplication with normal basis (especially the Gaussian normal basis (GNB))? Or can produce the matrix $M$?

Comment: IIRC an algorithm for producing a good normal basis (one with $M$ as sparse as possible) is described with pseudocode in *The Handbook of Applied Cryptography*.

Comment: I know it. But I want to know whether there exists some computer algebra system or other library including such a implementation.